# How Natural language processing and elasticsearch are related

Tags: nlp, beginner, career, self-study

I got call from a recruiter for an elasticsearch job. I am not sure how these 2 are related. Can anyone suggest and provide example use case?

Comment: ElasticSearch is a text search engine as can serve as a database. Simple use case can be as simple as providing recommendations based on input text like lyric search etc.

Answer (score 4):

> [Natural language processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) is a field of computer science, artificial intelligence, and computational linguistics.
>
> [ElasticSearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) is a search engine based on Lucene.

ElasticSearch uses parts of NLP (e.g., tokenization and stemming). ElasticSearch also includes software engineering elements to ensure a search solution is performant.

Since NLP is entire discipline, there are many parts of NLP that are not related to ElasticSearch.

Comment: can you suggest a list of pieces of NLP that elasticsearch uses, apart from tokenization and stemming?

Comment: Most NLP components of Elasticsearch are inherited from Lucene -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Lucene.